# Store in table pointers to rows from another table instead of using foreign keys

Tags: database-design, pointers, reference, rdbms, object-oriented-database

i'm just curious if it's possible to just use pointers  the c/java/etc. way instead of joining tables based on foreign key. And since we're on this topic, does postgres or any other  RDBMS  use pointers, when joining, to quickly locate  a row referenced by a foreign key instead of searching within the whole table containing FKs?

Comment: I've often wondered this. An RDBMS could secretly store a physical row pointer (like a PostgreSQL ctid) alongside the value in a foreign key column, and could then use it to find referenced rows without having to go via an index. However, it would need to be updated whenever the referenced table was compacted. Also, rows would be bigger, so IO bandwidth and cache would be more strained. Would there be a net performance benefit? Would it justify the increased complexity?

Answer (score 2):

An essential feature of the relational model of data is that it does not use pointers, structural links or address-based data access in its external, logical view of the database. Abolishing the use of pointers was in fact one of Codd's main motivations for inventing the relational model in 1969.

Pointers are of course used internally by most relational / SQL based DBMSs.

Comment: But are they used in this particular way? Does any database store a pointer to a referenced row on disk?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has something called ROWID which stores the physical address of a row in a table. They look something like `AAAA8mAALAAAAQkAAA` which can be broken down into:

- Data object nr (segment) `[AAAA8m]`
- Data file in tablespace `[AAL]`
- Data Block (within the data file) `[AAAAQk]`
- The row (within the block) `[AAA]`

Using the rowid is the fastest way of physically locating any row in a single block read. They are used internally, but can be used directly by the developer. Looking up a row by primary key, results in one (or a few) index reads to find the rowid, and then the database will locate the block and extract the row. If one knows the rowid, no index lookups are needed.

Having said that, one of the pillars of relational databases is that the model is supposed to be independent of physical storage (no pointers). Also, it enables a specific implementation (of a dbms) to optimize and provide additional features transparently.

Each time you use a rowid, a Unicorn will die, and poop falls down from heaven. For example, if you shrink a table, or update a partitioned table (causing a row to move to another partition) or if you are rebuilding a table, or export/import a table, or... or... or... the rowid will change.

In conclusion: rowid-based access does not provide enough benefits over regular indexed access to be worth the risk of the inevitable failure. Know that they exist and what they are, but don't ever rely on them.